# how to extract the value of the field in awk as variable

Tags: shell, awk

I have a sript that use nearly same code like below:

```
almsource=`awk -F# '{print $5}' test.csv`
for var in ${almsource[@]}
do
    ...
done

almSev=`awk -F# '{print $3}' test.csv`
for var in ${almSev[@]}
do
    ...
done
```

...
Since most of the code are the same, except the value in `awk -F# '{print $3}'` .
And I want to write a function, as extrat the field value in  `awk -F# '{print $3}' as varaible.
Below is my function, but it seems`
awk -F# '{print ${$varNum}}' is not correct.

```
getFieldGrp()
{
#getFieldGrp <fieldVar> 
varNum=$1
almfield=`awk -F# '{print ${$varNum}}' test.csv`
...
done
```

}

Can anyone help me with it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first pass the shell variable to `awk` and use an array to hold all the values. Try this:

```
array=($(awk -F "#" -v num="$1" '{ print $num }' test.csv))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. It mostly works. I think array=($(awk -F "#" -v num=2 '{print $num}' test.csv)) works. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. your solution greatly helped me with this problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please let me know if you have any problems. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Don't need awk for this

```
getFieldGrp() { cut -d '#' -f $1 test.csv; }

for word in $(getFieldGrp 5); do ...
```